# Why Can't I Delete Data From Mongo Atlas With This Code?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mern

I just want to ask

I tried deleting data from mongo atlas using this code

```
//DELETE POST
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.username === req.body.username) {
      try {
        await post.delete();
        res.status(200).json("Post has been deleted...");
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("You can delete only your post!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

But when I test it using Postman, it doesn't do anything and gives 500 internal server error.
[image: Postman to test the code]

Even though the data is in the mongo atlas, like this picture
[image: The data is inside]

I just want to know where I went wrong when writing this code, because I just started to create a project. Thank you for your attention!

```
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.userId === req.params.id) {
    if (req.body.password) {
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    }
    try {
      await Post.delete();
      res.status(200).json("Post has been deleted...");
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json("You can delete only your account!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using `express.json()` in your code? https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: of course I use it `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Is there any function named **delete()** in your code ?? if yes , please share it , So that we can see whats wrong in that.
Else, try replacing that line with **await Post.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);**

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You have two bits of code where you explicitly output 500 and try to convert the error to JSON. We can't tell which of them is triggering or what the error is. **Log it and read the error message!!**

Comment: @CharlieFernandis
I have added another delete() function code, which is in my project.

Comment: @seyn kindly show the function , error might be in that function

Answer (score 0):

```html
//DELETE POST
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.username === req.body.username) {
      try {
        post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json("Post has been deleted...");
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("You can delete only your post!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

This will work iguess, you can also use filter function.

```html
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.username === req.body.username) {
      const posts = await Post.find();
      const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => post.id !== req.params.id);
      res.status(200).json(filteredPosts);
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("You can delete only your post!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Similarly, your code doesn't crash when running, but it doesn't run to delete data from mongo atlas

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mongoose, you can use the prebuilt methods:

To find the post by ID you can run:

```
await Post.findById(postId)
```

To remove said post by ID the process is almost identical:

```
await Post.findByIdAndDelete(postId)
```